# Hammering a question: shouldn't both questions have that gold tag?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

I just bumped into this scenario:

- jquery gold badge user
- question 1 with only [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag
- question 2 with both [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) tag

jquery gold badge user managed to hammer (close) question 2 after question 1.

Now, in that specific scenario the user was right. However, I think this would be a more accurate action if **both** questions would have that tag.

Especially in this case, when [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) was the gold badge tag (so, a framework in that language) and not [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) (the language itself).

Shouldn't this action be possible only if both questions have that tag?

<sub>One could be an expert in Python + Youtube API but might not know the subtleties of JavaScript + Youtube API, and, as a Youtube API gold badge owner, might make a dupehammer mistake.</sub>

Comment: Eh? So, which question did get closed? Question 2? Are you sure that user _only_ has a jQuery gold badge?

Comment: Yes, question 2

Comment: Now he has both, but I just checked and user received gold badge for JavaScript 3 years later that question was closed so, **at the time the question was closed, user only had jquery gold badge**

Comment: Geez, Mjölnir is that old already?

Comment: So I wouldn't be able to close a Python or pandas question because the target has the tag, say, "grouping"? This would make the hammer practically useless.

Comment: @user2285236 I don't get why you think that. I didn't say "target has more tags" or "target doesn't have exact tags"

Comment: -1. (1) Then people cannot close anything as duplicate of [language-agnostic] questions. (2) We trust gold badge holders....

Comment: *"in that specific scenario the user was right"* - so do you have any evidence of a *problem*, where there have been misuses of the dupe hammer? It's not an irreversible action, unless there's a lot of abuse it seems pointless to do anything about it.

Answer (score 9):

The criteria say that you need to have a gold badge in one of the tags of the question that you're *closing*. You're expected to know what is, and what isn't a good duplicate of the question you're closing.

This means that a [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) null reference exception could be closed as a duplicate of a generic [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) null reference exception.

Your suggestion could prevent valid closures like that, if the tags are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Or, it could be that both questions are pure jQuery questions, both erroneously included any or all of [tag:javascript], [tag:html], [tag:css], and possibly [tag:web], and the target _omitted_ the [tag:jquery] tag.